# Get Azure HybridWorker Environement Variable in Powershell

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-automation, azure-runbook, azure-hybrid-connections

I have an Azure Powershell Runbook which is used to invoke a java jar inside the Hybrid Worker Groups.

Currently we pass the absolute java path and run the program, Iwant to change this and pass JAVA_HOME instead. I have set java home as environment variable and is able to access inside the hybrid worker.

```
$java = $Env:JAVA_HOME
Write-Output "$java"
```

this give the right path when ran inside the hybrid.

When passing this value via runbook it is not returning any value. The `Write-Output` returns empty when running via Automation Runbooks

```
$java = $Env:JAVA_HOME
Write-Output "$Env:JAVA_HOME"
$arguments = "-cp C:\\prgm\jws\jar\jwsClient-0.0.1.jar"
$p = Start-Process -FilePath $java  -ArgumentList $arguments
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion.  Based on my experience, JAVA_HOME is usually used to store JDK path while in development. And to run a jar, we just need JRE.

But, I am not sure how Azure runbook sets its environment variables. You can output all environment variables as following:

```
Get-ChildItem env:* | sort-object name
```

If you know which variable stores the path of JRE, you may retrieve it with script then.